# How to take a layer's snapshot with mask layer?

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics

I added a mask to UIView's layer:

```
CGImageRef maskImageRef = [UIImage imageNamed:"Icon.png"].CGImage; 
CALayer maskLayer = [CALayer layer];
maskLayer.contents = (__bridge id)maskImageRef;
self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Then I use this code to get snapshot from a UIView:

```
[self.layer renderInContext:mainViewContentContext];
```

But the mask wasn't drawn.

How to draw self.layer with mask?

Special thx!

Comment: possible duplicate of [layer.renderInContext doesn't take layer.mask into account?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896296/layer-renderincontext-doesnt-take-layer-mask-into-account)

Comment: layerA.renderInContext will not  render layerA's mask layer in context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to fix this can be to use **Quartz** functions

Use    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, maskImage) inside drawRect method

Refer [CGContextClipToMask example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344767/how-to-draw-a-shape-on-top-of-a-uiimage-while-respecting-the-images-alpha-mask) link for help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344767/how-to-draw-a-shape-on-top-of-a-uiimage-while-respecting-the-images-alpha-mask

Comment: It's a lot of work doing this. i must handle transforms on mask layer, main layer and view by my self.i really used four days draw them with quartzcore.

Answer (score 2):

You have to screenshot of the screen try this code:

```
CGRect screenRect =CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-44); 
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);

CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];

UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, self, nil, nil);
```

i hope help you.

Comment: self.view.layer will not clip to it's mask layer when it "renderInContenxt:" :~(