# How to render screenshot from uiview to uiimage after apply mask to layer

Tags: ios, screenshot, layer, mask

i create kaleidoscope effect from uiview .it use a loft of sublayer and sublayer mask .
then i use below code for render uiimage from uiview.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

[image]

render image as below:

[image]

**The problem is the render image doesn't render mask effect.**

Comment: It looks like you need to make usage of CGContextClipToMask - did u check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076534/how-to-take-a-layers-snapshot-with-mask-layer?

Comment: i already check that ,but still not understand how to implement : (

Comment: ios7 already fixed this issue : )